# Can't send the target ID from a view to the controller "ondrop" event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, viewcontroller

I am using c# MVC 4 , i am trying to drop an text into an img class and send the img ID to the controller :

```
<img ... ondrop="drop(this,event);">

function drag(target, e) {

    e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', target.id);

}

function drop(target, e) {

    var id = e.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    target.appendChild(document.getElementById(id));
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MyAction")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { imgId: target.id },            
    });

}
```

and

```
public ActionResult AddFriendToVIrtualFriend(string imgId)
{
    ...
}
```

The string sent to the controller is always empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to add [HttpPost] in your controller action

Comment: Did you try sending data using `JSON.stringify(data: { imgId: target.id })`?